# UILabel (or UITextField) with Title Label

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

So, I've tried looking all around for information on how to recreate a UILabel (ideally, or a UITextField) with a title (for lack of better work).

Since it's quite hard to explain (half the reason I couldn't find what I was looking for) I've attached an image from the Facebook App.

How would I go about creating labels like this? Either single, or multiple?

Sorry for the simple question, still new to iPhone development.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing it in a `UITableView` like the one shown in your capture, you can use the `UITableViewCell textLabel` property to display a standard left aligned label. Then you only add the `UITextField` to the cell.

I've done exactly this in an app, it looks good and is pretty simple.

UPDATE:
Something like this (untested, may have some typos):

```
UITextField *textField = nil;
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueCellWithReuseIdentifier: kIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault];
    textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    textField.tag = 12345;
    [cell addSubview: textField];
    textField.frame = CGRectMake(50, 5, 70, 25);
}
else
{
    textField = [cell viewWithTag: 12345];
}
```

UPDATE2: UITextField wasn't added to UITableCellView.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to setup a UITableView like that?

Comment: Mmmm, not here. You want to do the dequeueWithReuseIdentifier: as usual, then when not found, create a UITextField, give it a tag, and get it back when needed. Well, let's edit my post :)

Comment: Thanks for that. Creating the textField is straight forward enough, but how do I put that into the cell?

Comment: Excellent! That's enough information for me to solve the problem at hand. Ta!